# what is {version} in ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundle, single-page-application

I try to get started with MVC SPA apps, and I noticed in BundleConfig the following:

```
 ScriptBundle("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
```

How this works? What is {version} and where it it taken from?

And where can find more information this, how BundleConfig works and how to customize it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [{version} wildcard in MVC4 Bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029161/version-wildcard-in-mvc4-bundle)

Comment: Better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029161/version-wildcard-in-mvc4-bundle

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029161/version-wildcard-in-mvc4-bundle).

Also, check out [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/16/asp-net-4-5-asp-net-mvc-4-asp-net-web-pages-2-and-visual-studio-2012-web-developer-features.aspx). The *Bundling and Optimization* section discusses the use of the `{version}` tag.

Answer (score 4):

It allows you to indicate a version number format (semver) that many libraries use. For example, you reference jquery-1.9.1 and then it goes to jquery-1.9.2. Using {version} you don't have to change your code, you just need to re build the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answers are sufficient enough, just wanted to show the technical detail mentioned in the [answer link by Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12041931/2822211):

> The -{version} basically maps to a version regex, or to be precise: (\d+(?:.\d+){1,3}).

HTH.