# MVC Bundle.Include() VirtualPath syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default there are these code lines in the asp.net mvc solution

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

So if I have these files

```
jquery.validate.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
jquery.validate-vsdoc.js
jquery-1.10.2.js
jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.js
jquery-1.10.2.min.map
```

which of them will be included in the rendered page? And what do these symbols ***{version}***, *******  mean? I understand {version} is replaced by the number 1.10.2, but what rule is used with * ?

Comment: Both are explained in [{version} wildcard in MVC4 Bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029161/version-wildcard-in-mvc4-bundle).

Comment: Jquery{version} will include only jquery-1.10.2.js

Comment: @szpic yes but what will happen with jquery.validate.js and
jquery.validate.min.js according to * symbol?

Answer (score 0):

First bundle will render:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

and  jquery.validate bundle will render:

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

as you can see * means that will be included all files.

@update

Above is in debug mode
in release min files will be included like here:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

vsdoc file is intellisense for visual studio. So there is no point in including this file in webpage

Comment: why is .min ignored? it considered in the c# code? And what about jquery.validate-vsdoc.js ?

Comment: yes, I know there is no point in including this file, but HOW MVC KNOW that there is no point in including this file? beacause if I create jquery.validate-TEMP.js it will include in the page

Comment: It's not explained in details. On the asp.net site you can only find info that compiler ignore -vsdoc.js file/intellisense file in redenring. [Click](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) Ofc you can create your own filtering mechanism and ignore temp ;)